# How to customize the protocol specifier of an http response?

Tags: http, go

I have the requirement to send HTTP packets with a protocol
specifier other than `HTTP/...`
I use the `http.Response` to create packets

```
resp := new(http.Response)
resp.Status = "200 OK"
resp.StatusCode = http.StatusOK
resp.ProtoMajor = 1
resp.ProtoMinor = 0
resp.Proto = "EVENT/1.0"
```

I set the `Proto` field, but at the end the written bytes still contains
`HTTP/1.0 200 OK` because that's hardcoded in [response.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/response.go)

```
216 if _, err := io.WriteString(w, "HTTP/"+protoMajor+"."+protoMinor+" "+statusCode+text+"\r\n"); err != nil {
217 return err
218 }
```

Is there a reason why the Proto field is ignored?

Comment: I guess it's because an HTTP response object.

Comment: The type's used by both servers and clients, and I think `Proto`'s there to be read when you're the client. Seems understandable to fork `net/http` if you're building a non-HTTP server, though life might be simpler if you can somehow make this vanilla HTTP.